# How to a predict the delivery estimate date from the historical data?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation

[image: This is the dataset]

**I NEED TO PREDICT THE DELIVERY TIME FOR ANY RANDOM DATE/TIME FROM THESE HISTORICAL DATA**

I have tried to take the difference between each step. I have to predict the delivery time for a given process and I have not sure what to use. I tried using linear regression but it didn't help. Any help from your side will be appreciated!

Should I try a time series to predict the value? or Should I use some other regression model?
Which time series model will be a good fit?

The formula time I used for linear regression

total time = transfer_delivered - tranfer_created

created2received = transfer_created - tranfer_received

received2convert = transfer_convert - tranfer_received

convert2send_out= transfer_sendOut - tranfer_convert

send_out_delivery = transfer_delivered - tranfer_send_out

total time = created2received +received2convert + convert2send_out + send_out_delivery

When I did that, it is giving me the same exact result for each value for both the training and test set
which means R-squared is 1

Any help or tips will be appreciated !!

PS. **THERE IS NO OTHER COLUMN GIVEN**

Comment: Welcome to this site. I think this question needs a bit more structure and context. What is the meaning of the single columns? What is the actual target variable you want to predict? At which point in time do you want to make a prediction (i.e. when you want to make a prediction at the point where the customer places an order then the columns except for payment method are not available to you!)? A time series approach does only make sense if you have events that are ordered and 'depend on each other'. For example, ...

Comment: a TS approach would be to insert a feature like 'how long did the transfer take the last time for this customer [with this payment method]?'

Comment: Thank you!
There is no target variable. I believe we need to create it on our own. Basically, the entire motive is to estimate how much time does a transfer(at any random time) will take.
For example: on March 15, we need to predict, how long the transfer will take for someone (1/3)

Comment: Now coming to the meaning of columns, I think it is pretty much understandable. The first  column gives you at time at which a user created/ started the process of transfer. The second is the time at which it is received by the company which is doing the transfer and so on...

Comment: What we need to do is : we need to estimate the time for any random user coming to that particular company and doing a transfer based on all these historical data.(3/3)

Comment: Please do not put it into the comments but rather edit you question, make it shorter and more self contained. For example: I think there is a target column (as you said, you need to create it from the columns)... please describe in a short sentence what the target column is and how you compute it.